# Как сделать что бы переключатель "checkbox" видел "value" как "radio"?

Tags: javascript

```js
var but = document.forms.burger.elements.order;
var sizeBurger =document.forms.burger.elements.sizeBurger;
var stuff =document.forms.burger.elements.stuff;

but.addEventListener('click',function(){
  console.log(sizeBurger.value)
  console.log(stuff.value)
})
```

```html
<form name="burger">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Select size</legend>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="sizeBurger" value="small"/>Small
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="sizeBurger" value="large"/>Large
    </label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Select stuffing</legend>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="stuff" value="cheese"/>Cheese
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="stuff" value="salad"/>Salad
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="stuff" value="potato"/>Potato
    </label>
  </fieldset>
  <input type="button" value="ORDER" name="order">
</form>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните ваш вопрос. Что вы хотите сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`radio` имеет одно значение, в отличии от `checkbox`, поэтому его стоит проверять иным способом:

```js
var but = document.forms.burger.elements.order;
var sizeBurger =document.forms.burger.elements.sizeBurger;
var stuff =document.forms.burger.elements.stuff;

but.addEventListener('click',function(){
  console.log(sizeBurger.value)
  for(var i in stuff){
   if(stuff.hasOwnProperty(i)){
          console.log(stuff[i].value, stuff[i].checked)
        }
  }
})
```

```html
<form name="burger">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Select size</legend>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="sizeBurger" value="small"/>Small
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="sizeBurger" value="large"/>Large
    </label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Select stuffing</legend>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="stuff" value="cheese"/>Cheese
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="stuff" value="salad"/>Salad
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="stuff" value="potato"/>Potato
    </label>
  </fieldset>
  <input type="button" value="ORDER" name="order">
</form>
```

Comment: мне нужно получить значение checkbox т,е value

Comment: Ну так и проверяйте, что значение `checked === true` и если так, то выполняйте операцию над значением

Answer (score 0):

```
but.addEventListener('click',function(){
  console.log(sizeBurger.value)
  for(var i in stuff){
    if(stuff.hasOwnProperty(i)){
        if(stuff[i].checked===true){
            console.log(stuff[i].value)}

        }
  }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Получить массив `value` всех чекнутых (лол) чекбоксов можно в две строки:

```js
const frm = document.forms.burger; 
function getCbValues() {
  let checked  = frm.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked'),  // 1
      valueArr = Array.from(checked).map(n => n.value);                   // 2
  console.clear(); 
  console.log(JSON.stringify(valueArr)); 
}
```

```html
<form name="burger">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Select size</legend>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="sizeBurger" value="small"/>Small
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="sizeBurger" value="large"/>Large
    </label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Select stuffing</legend>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="stuff" value="cheese"/>Cheese
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="stuff" value="salad"/>Salad
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="stuff" value="potato"/>Potato
    </label>
  </fieldset>
  <input type="button" value="ORDER" name="order">&emsp;<button id="get-cbxs" type="button" onclick="getCbValues()">Получить values</button>

</form>
```